# The variable name '@VarName' has already been declared Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inserting multiple items into table based on a selection from drop down list.  When I select one item from the drop down then everything works fine but when I select multiple items then I get this error

```
The variable name '@CompName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

what am i doing wrong?  thanks
here is my code

```
protected void DV_Test_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem listItem in cblCustomerList.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Selected)
            {
                string Name= listItem.Value;
                sqlcon.Open();
                string CompName= ((TextBox)DV_Test.FindControl("txtCompName")).Text.ToString();
                string Num = ((TextBox)DV_Test.FindControl("txtNum")).Text.ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CompNamefrom MyTable where CompName= '" + CompName+ "' and Num = '" + Num + "' and Name= '" + Name+ "'    ", sqlcon);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Not Valid";
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();

                    sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(CompName, Num, Name) VALUES(@CompName, @Num, @Name)";
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CompName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CompName;
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Num;
                    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;                 
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DV_Test.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
                    sqlcon.Close();
                }
                sqlcon.Close();               
            }

         }
 }
```

Comment: You also should sanitize your inputs and use parameters in that select statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the paramters `@CompName` and `@Num` to your query every time through the loop.

You need to move the call to `Add` outside the loop and use the following to update them:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters["@CompName"].Value = CompName;
sqlcmd.Parameters["@Num"].Value = Num;
```

So your code becomes:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(CompName, Num, Name) VALUES(@CompName, @Num, @Name)";
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CompName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Num", SqlDbType.VarChar);

foreach (ListItem listItem in cblCustomerList.Items)
{
    if (....)
    {
        ....
    }
    else
    {
        dr.Close();

        sqlcmd.Parameters["@CompName"].Value = CompName;
        sqlcmd.Parameters["@Num"].Value = Num;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;                 
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DV_Test.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
        sqlcon.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks.  i fixed it using the clear function like this: DS.SelectParameters.Clear();

Answer (score 5):

Add `sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();` at the end. This way every parameter will not exist at the end of each loop.

Example:

```
// ...
sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(CompName, Num, Name) VALUES(@CompName, @Num, @Name)";
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@CompName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CompName;
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Num;
                    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;                 
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DV_Test.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
                    sqlcon.Close();
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

My assumption here is because you've declared `sqlcmd` outside of the scope of the loop; so when you iterate over it, you could potentially be adding in the same parameter name multiple times.

And please please please fix this line:  `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CompNamefrom MyTable where CompName= '" + CompName+ "' and Num = '" + Num + "' and Name= '" + Name+ "'    ", sqlcon);`  as it's SQL injection waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
SqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

in your code, before parameter adding. It will clear already added parameters list and consider your parameters as new.