# sql in for loop

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The variable name ‘@VarName’ has already been declared Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868128/the-variable-name-varname-has-already-been-declared-issue)

```
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp4.Count; i++)
    {
        #region idsetter

        int prevId = 0;

        command.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM Configuration";
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader[0].ToString() != "")
                {
                    prevId = Int32.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    prevId = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
        int currId = prevId + 1;
        #endregion
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Configuration (id,A, B, C, D, E, F,G) " + 
                              "VALUES (@id, @a, @b , @c, @d, @e, @f, @g)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", currId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", myL);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", pipi);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", temp4[i].ad);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", temp4[i].asa);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", temp4[i].Tasa);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", j);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", 1);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        j++;
        if (j > 7)
        {
            j = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write in Configuration Table first reading id and increment it and then writing everything else. But when second entry is being added it gives exception

> The variable name "@id"  has already been declared. Variable names
>   must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

How to avoid this exception any work around ?

Comment: I'm about 84% sure that once you've set the `CommandText` once, you don't need to set it again; you can just keep reusing the statement with different parameters.  You may want to have two statements and set them up outside the loop, in order to ensure they don't get recompiled every time.  It's not a huge deal, but you might as well take advantage of the benefits of prepared statements... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your Command parameters in every iteration of your loop.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Configuration (id,A, B, C, D, E, F,G) VALUES (@id, @a, @b , @c, @d, @e, @f, @g)";

command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", currId);
```

Comment: smaller ans simple solution

Answer (score 6):

If you add same parameter each time then it will always give you an exception.

Declare the variables just before for loop and give them some default value like :

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", "");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", "");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", "");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", "");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", "");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", 1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", 1);
```

and then change the value of parameters after `command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Configuration (id,A, B, C, D, E, F,G) VALUES (@id, @a, @b , @c, @d, @e, @f, @g)";` like

```
cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value=currId;
cmd.Parameters["@a"].Value=myL;
cmd.Parameters["@b"].Value=pipi;
cmd.Parameters["@c"].Value=temp4[i].ad;
cmd.Parameters["@d"].Value=temp4[i].asa;
cmd.Parameters["@e"].Value=temp4[i].Tasa;
cmd.Parameters["@f"].Value=j;
cmd.Parameters["@g"].Value=1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Right now, the parameter from your first query is conflicting with a parameter from your second query.  Use a new command for every execution.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding @id and all your other parameters multiple times to the parameter collection. You need to clear the collection first and then add the new record.

You should be able to use the clear method. [Clear parameter collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
command.Parameters.Clear();
```